# Pareto distribution parameter estimation with Scilab, why am I getting this enormous values?

Tags: distribution, tail, scilab, log-likelihood

Pareto distribution has two parameters (β,ξ), from the log likelihood maximization problem we get:
[image]

I am trying to estimate with Scilab the parameters for a simulated stock log return (2000 periods of time). My code is very easy:

```
time=[0:2000]';
dt=1/1000;
dWt=rand(2000,1,'normal')*sqrt(dt);
dWt(1)=0;
S0=100;
St(1)=S0;
mub=.07;
sigmab=.20;
for i=2:2000
St(i)=St(i-1)+St(i-1)*mub*dt+St(i-1)*sigmab*dWt(i);
end
Rp=diff(log(St));
```

I consider the worse `Nu` log returns changed of sign starting from the given `u` threshold:

```
Rpo=-Rp;
u=0.5*dt;
x=Rpo(Rpo>u);
```

Estimating the two parameters via log-likelihood maximization (the two derivatives equal to zero have been both multiplied for 1/Nu which gives the mean of the xi):

```
deff('[y]=eq(h)','y=[1/h(1)/h(2)-(1/h(1)+1)/h(2)*mean((1+h(1)*(x-u)/h(2))^(-1));-(1/h(1)+1)/h(1)+1/h(1)^2*mean(log(1+h(1)*(x-u)/h(2)))+(1/h(1)+1)/h(1)*mean((1+h(1)*(x-u)/h(2))^(-1))]');
[xoptim,v,inf]=fsolve([0.01;0.01],eq)
```

I expected the two parameters to be reasonable low, instead I get:

```
xoptim  = 

   9.95D+108
   2.01D+111
 v  = 

  -4.96D-112
  -2.45D-114
 inf  = 

   2.
```

Which means "number of calls to fcn reached" so the results does not converge. Why? I tried multiple times, and simulated value of log returns behavior should be very similar to empirical ones. Thank you in advance for helping me.

Update: if I change `sigmab` up to .32 or more I get what I want. Is this due to the fact that Pareto distribution does not apply if log returns are normally distributed (even in the worse `Nu` simulations) so to let returns be pareto distributed I should have them vary more over time?

Log likelihood function code for Scilab:

```
Nu=size(x,1);
N=size(Rp,1);
f=log(Nu/N*1/h(2))-(1/h(1)+1)*mean(log(1+h(1)*(x-u)/h(2)))
```

Comment: Why don't you try to directly minimize minus the log likelihood using `optim` and use the exact gradient you already calculated ? Using an optimisation algorithm (instead of solving the first-order optimality condition) will ensure descent whereas `fsolve` won't.

Comment: Can you give the Pareto distribution you are using ?

Comment: I used `fsolve` because I was thinking that because `optim` requires to input the derivatives with respect of the two parameters of interest it was straight to use `fsolve`.  The pareto CDF is `F_u(x)=1-(1+csi*(x-u)/beta)^(-1/csi)`

Comment: Please validate for me the log likelihood : `-\sum_{i=1}^{N} \ln \beta-(1/\xi+1)\ln(1+\xi\frac{x_i-u}{\beta}))`

Comment: Log likelihood is (latex-language) `$$N_u \cdot \ln \left( \frac{N_u}{N} \cdot \frac{1}{\beta} \right) - \left( \frac{1}{\xi}+1 \right) \cdot \sum_{i=1}{N_u} \ln \left( 1+ \xi \cdot \frac{(x_i-u)}{\beta} \right) $$`

Comment: Where `N_u` is the number of observations bigger than `u`, `u` is the threshold (arbitrarily chosen), and `N` is the total number of observations (the ones below plus the ones above the threshold)

Comment: OK just add in the question the Scilab code of the log-likelihood and I will help you with `optim` (or another one).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234621/discussion-between-barbab-and-stephane-mottelet).